# New laptop can't connect to Wi-Fi

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, lenovo-laptop

I have recently bought a new Lenovo Ideapad s300 laptop and installed Windows 7 64bit on it.

For some reason, the laptop can't connect to any wireless network. I did install the Lenovo network drivers, but it didn't help. When I look at the network adapter settings there is no wireless network adapter detected.

What could cause this problem?

Comment: You may have installed Ethernet NIC drivers but not Wireless NIC drivers

Comment: Can you see the device or any unknown devices in device manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the wireless adapter is not showing up, it sounds like a missing driver.

You need to find out what wireless adapter you have as there are three or four drivers for this model.

This can be done here at [lenovo.com  which wlan driver?](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?AliasID=which-wlan-driver). Follow the directions then install the correct driver from [support.lenovo.com s300 drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/en_NO/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT074467).

Once the drivers are installed, Windows should detect the adapter. This may require a restart.